# Unable to access jmeter variables in pepperbox or kafkameter

Tags: apache-kafka, jmeter-5.0

I want to run a small load test using jmeter. I am using kafkameter library to produce kafka messages. Is there a way to access jmeter variables using ${} or vars.get() in kafkameter.

```
Kafka message - 
{
  "id": "${id}",
  "book": [
    {
      "uuid": "${uuId}",
      "version": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

The "${id}" and "${uuId}" values are not substituted in messages. Is there anything that I am missing here.